# In C++ program how to call a constructor of C++ class which in dynamic library(.so)

Tags: c++, constructor, shared-libraries

I can call a common function of C++ class which in dynamic library(.so),but I do not know how to call a constructor of C++ class which in dynamic library(.so).

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_hellobreakdd_MainActivity_helloBreak (JNIEnv *, jobject){

void *handle;

double (*cosine)(double);

char *error;

handle = dlopen("libtest.so", RTLD_NOW);

if (!handle) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "start", dlerror());
}

*(void **) (&cosine) = dlsym(handle, "Add");

printf("%f\n", (*cosine)(2.0));

dlclose(handle);

return 1;
```

}

Comment: First you need a *class* ...

Comment: then,What I need to do?Any help will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructors cannot be called manually/directly. So you have to create an object in your shared object something like shown below,

```
class shape {
 public:
    void draw();
};
extern "C" {
 Shape *maker(){
  return new Shape();
}
```

In this case you need a header file of the class shape to type-cast from void pointer. say,

```
void *mkr = dlsym(hndl, "maker");  // get maker method symbol 
shape *my_shape = static_cast<shape *()>(mkr)(); //get the shape object
```

If you don't want C based function call then you have to find the mangled name and use it to call the maker() function and avoid "extern c". you can use nm command to get the symbols in the .so file in this case.

Instead, Create a global object in the shared object and use the above method to get the object instance. In this case constructor will be called when you open the shared object using dlopen().

Hope this helps for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of a class is called when you initialize the instance of that class and thus make a object,

```
MyClass MyInstance(param);
```

Assuming `MyClass` is a class, and `param` is the paramiters to be passed to the constructor, this will call the constructor or `MyClass`

Answer (score 0):

Incase modifying the .so is not an option. We can manually create an object of c++ class from .so, by calling the new and constructor functions accordingly.

Usually, compiler does this kind of job, but we can do it by some inline assembly code.

Here is an example of creation a dummy class object in x86 code:

```
asm volatile {
    "mov $1, %%edi\n"
    "callq *%2\n"
    "mov %%rax, %%rbx\n"
    "mov %%rbx, %%rdi\n"
    "callq *%1\n"
    "mov %%rbx, %0\n"
    : =m "my_pointer"
    : m "dummy_new", m "dummy_constructor"
    : "%edi", "%rax", "%rbx", "%rdi"
}
```